# list Remove method does not remove list item

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have an ASP.Net web app written in C# and it has a `List<Employee>` object called AffectedEmployees, where Employee is a class I've written. AffectedEmployees is also a property of another class I've written called LitHoldDetails, but I don't think that's pertinent; I just include the information in case I'm wrong, which has, of course, never happened. ;) Anyway, I need to remove a particular Employee object from AffectedEmployees. I first just did a `Remove()` (`Add()` works, BTW), but the Employee in question was not removed from AffectedEmployees. So I checked to make sure it was really there by doing a call to `Contains()`. `Contains()` doesn't find the Employee in AffectedEmployees, but if I examine the list and compare it to the Employee in the debugger, the Employee is indeed in Affected Employees. I've compared the two with a fine tooth comb and I see no difference in the data. What am I doing wrong?  Here's my code:

```
Employee emp = new Employee().FindByLogin(item.Key.ToString());
if (CurrentLitHoldDetails.AffectedEmployees.Contains(emp))
    CurrentLitHoldDetails.AffectedEmployees.Remove(emp);
```

Note: `FindByLogin()` initiates emp and fills it with data. `item.Key.ToString()` is coming from a Hashtable that contains all the Employees I need to remove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new `Employee` object that couldn't possibly exist in the list yet, then trying to remove it. So it doesn't find that exact object (even if the *contents* of the new `Employee` object match some other `Employee` object in the list) and doesn't remove it. If you place a breakpoint on the line with `Remove` on it, you'll see it doesn't get hit.

Try using `RemoveAll` to remove all elements matching some condition. *(I'm doing a bit of guessing here since I don't know what your classes look like exactly.)*

```
CurrentLitHoldDetails.AffectedEmployees.RemoveAll(x => x.Login == item.Key.ToString());
```

Comment: Well, that explains it. So simple. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

`Remove` and `Contains` test for the presence of the exact object you're trying to remove, not just one with identical data.  So when you create a new `Employee` object, it's looking for that exact object.  It doesn't find it, because that exact object has never been added to `AffectedEmployees`.

This is called "reference equality" and is the default behavior.  If you want `Remove` and `Contains` to determine equality based on property values, you will need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on your `Employee` object.  (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Microsoft's documentation on `Object.GetHashCode()`.)

Comment: Ann, your answer is perfect and I've upvoted it, but I marked Grant's as the answer because his suggestion with RemoveAll() was a lot simpler than overriding Equals and GetHashCode. Still, thank you very much!